# relationship between EditText and TextView

Tags: android, android-edittext

If I have an EditText in layout and Text view in another layout my code take which in EditText to another layout and put it in the textView ..

the format of TextView is different from format of EditText like font-size and font-family .. i want my code to take the format also to another layout and apply it on textview which exist in another layout

so to be more specific : I write something in the 1st layout and change its font size ... this EditText will be a textView in the second layout but without saving format of EditText .. I want textView be same format of EditText ..

can I do that ?? and how ??

```
spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner);
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
    this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, items);
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(
          new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
              @Override
              public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                      int arg2, long arg3) {
                int position = spinner.getSelectedItemPosition();
                int fontSizeInt;
                try
                {
                    fontSizeInt = Integer.parseInt(items[position]);
                }
                catch (NumberFormatException e)
                {
                    fontSizeInt = 12; // Default size.
                }
                et.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, (float) fontSizeInt);

                  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
              }
              @Override
              public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
              }
          }
      );
```

and this is my touch listener 
  public void addListenerOnImageg1() {

```
final Context context = this;

imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.g1);

imageView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {



    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {

  Intent intent1 = new Intent(context , g1.class); 
  intent1.putExtra("fname" , et.getText().toString());
  intent1.putExtra("font_size", fontSizeInt);
  startActivity(intent1);


    }

}); }
```

what should i write in the second layout ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you do let user change format of the text in `EditText`, keep those changes, put 'em as more extras to your `Intent`, and read extras in the other activity.

You should have only one `Intent` and one call to `startActivity()`, unless you really want to start two activities, which I doubt.

I don't see where format data is, from this code, but if you have, for instance, your font size stored in `int fontSize`, call:

```
intent.putExtra("font_size", fontSize);
```

In that other activity, call:

```
int receivedFontSize = intent.getIntExtra("font_size", defaultFontSize);
```

As defaultFontSize, put 12 instead of the variable, if it's 12. Put 18, if it's 18. The purpose of this variable is to avoid absence of the value passed from parent activity. For instance:

```
int receivedFontSize = intent.getIntExtra("font_size", 18);
```